# How to create smooth transition between styles in a time-lapse using Darktable?

Tags: timelapse, darktable

I'm having fun with making time-lapses and I'm using Darktable for color correction. The problem I have is that for the scenes like a sunset where the beginning and the end of the time-lapse are of different exposure and color, I want to apply a different formula in Darktable.

This causes an issue since there will be at least two sets of images with different styles applied to them. Such a setting will result in a jump from one color correction to another when the time-lapse images are converted into a video. What I think is the right approach is to ask Darktable to make a transition from one style to another, starting from the beginning of the image list, heading to the end.

Is there any way I can accomplish this using Darktable? What are my solutions in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I didn't find a way to do that with darktable, I developed a script to use `darktable-cli` and to interpolate between darktable's parameters:

https://github.com/ziadloo/darktable_transition

It's not much but it does the job (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question for Darktable specifically , but in general you need software that allows for the creation of keyframes and the interpolation of parameters between those keyframes.

The only software that I know that does this for RAW photo files is [LRTimelapse](https://lrtimelapse.com/) (no affiliation).
It is used in conjunction with Lightroom, but as it alters the sidecar xmp files perhaps it can be used with other RAW editors as well.